# unmet dependencies while installing ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Tags: ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, 64bit, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, and naturally tried to upgrade to ROS Fuerte. My laptop has the following specifications:

Memory: 1.9 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T8100 @ 2.10GHz × 2
Graphics: Intel® 965GM
OS Type: 64-bit

I have been installing-removing-installing-removing ROS Fuerte again and again and keep on getting the following error.

> Selecting previously unselected
> package ros-fuerte-desktop-full.
> Unpacking ros-fuerte-desktop-full
> (from
> .../ros-fuerte-desktop-full_1.0.0-s1347207966~precise_amd64.deb)
> ... Errors were encountered while
> processing:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned
> an error code (1)

and also the fact that Ubuntu reported error message saying

> 'Error: Broken count>0' This usually
> means that your installed packages
> have unmet dependencies

I upgraded libassimp via synaptic, so now I have libassimp2-d-dev, libassimp3.0 ...

Then, I tried

> sudo apt-get -f install

I get the following messages.

> Reading package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree        Reading state
> information... Done Correcting
> dependencies... Done The following
> packages were automatically installed
> and are no longer required:   kdesudo
> update-manager-kde Use 'apt-get
> autoremove' to remove them. The
> following extra packages will be
> installed:   libassimp-dev The
> following NEW packages will be
> installed:   libassimp-dev 0 upgraded,
> 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 132
> not upgraded. 5 not fully installed or
> removed. Need to get 0 B/94.4 kB of
> archives. After this operation, 470 kB
> of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
> (Reading database ... 413855 files and
> directories currently installed.)
> Unpacking libassimp-dev (from
> .../libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_amd64.deb)
> ... dpkg: error processing
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite
> '/usr/include/assimp/Compiler/poppack1.h',
> which is also in package
> libassimp3.0-r1264-dev
> 3.0.1264.10-ubuntu1~precise1 No apport report written because MaxReports is
> reached already
> Errors were encountered while
> processing:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned
> an error code (1)

I have read a few threads on unmet dependencies, still, I'm not sure what to fix.

Thread 1: http://answers.ros.org/question/43369/unmet-dependencies-for-fuerte-desktop-full-on-1204/

Thread 2: http://answers.ros.org/question/42596/unmet-dependency-on-eigen-for-vision-opencv-now-cant-install-or-upgrade-any-fuerte-packages/

Anyhow, ROS is running whenever I call roscore, but I will not be able to create overlay, since I cannot do this (synaptic will prompt me to remove some ros related packages like ros-desktop-full etc):

> sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall python-rosdep

in which I will get the following messages

> The following packages have unmet
> dependencies:  python-rosinstall :
> Depends: mercurial but it is not going
> to be installed
> Depends: bzr but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: python-vcstools but it is not going to
> be installed  ros-fuerte-robot-model :
> Depends: libassimp-dev but it is not
> going to be installed
> ros-fuerte-visualization : Depends:
> libassimp-dev but it is not going to
> be installed E: Unmet dependencies.
> Try 'apt-get -f install' with no
> packages (or specify a solution).

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44033/unmet-dependencies-while-installing-ros-fuerte-on-ubuntu-12.04-64-bit/) by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-09-19**:
Was this the solution?!   I have exactly the same problem. I upgraded my Ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04 and Fuerte will not install due to the same errors as above.

**Comment by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on 2012-09-21**:
I have not yet found a solution :(.. tried uninstalling 'libassimp2-dev', and then installed 'libassimp2' and then unistalling it, basically i tried every possible libassimp in synaptic.....

**Comment by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on 2012-09-25**:
solved by removing libassimp3.0 and installed libassimp-dev... allenh1's solution was right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try removing libassimp-dev and the other problems you are having trouble with. You likely have a newer version installed.

If this doesn't work, start the system install over. To do this without losing any data,
I recommend you install as you usually would, but DO NOT format the drive. Doing so will erase your data. By not formatting the drive, you can keep the data but override the operating system files.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2